# How to install html5lib-0.90 library for Python on Windows?

Tags: python, html5lib

I'm using Windows, and trying to install html5lib-0.90 library on python

```
C:\>python C:\Users\Junior\Downloads\Python\html5lib-0.90\setup.py install
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Junior\Downloads\Python\html5lib-0.90\setup.py", line 36, in <module>
for name in os.listdir(os.path.join('src','html5lib'))
WindowsError: [Error 3] The system cannot find the path specified: 'src\\html5lib/*.*'
```

Is it possible to install this library on windows?

Is there a tutorial or installation manual?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try:

```
C:\>cd \Users\Junior\Downloads\Python\html5lib-0.90\
C:\Users\Junior\Downloads\Python\html5lib-0.90>python setup.py install
```